# How to prove a sequence $\{...,-6,-5,-4,5,6,7,8,... \}$ is not representable by a formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

I wanted to know why a sequence like the above cannot be represented by a function. Is there any cue here?

---

Sorry for my lack of knowledge that such sequence can have a formula (or functions) generating the same. I am very indebted to all the comments and answers to opening my mind to such sequences being representable by a formula.

I request any source(s) (in book, or web-site, whatever) that asks such questions and gives good practice or theoretical basis.

Comment: What do mean by "representable by a function"?

Comment: Like a formula that states the elements in the set. E.g $\{ 4n+1, n \in \mathbb {Z}\}$. There should be a cue that helps one to see. I plotted on number line, all have same image $0$, so still a mapping.

Comment: In that case, you have to be _very_ specific about which functions you allow. Because I am pretty certain that I can represent that set if I'm allowed to freely use things like square roots, floor functions and absolute values. It may not be pretty, but I can't imagine that it's impossible.

Comment: @Arthur Very good, but please show it.

Comment: It might be cheating, but any sequence can represented by its [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function). But since you didn't specify any rule, it technically counts. A good idea to formalize 'sensible representation` is to impose a finiteness condition: a sequence is representable iff there exists a finite formula that represents it.

Comment: @Arthur I am actually amazed by your comment to be able to show a suitable formula for generating the terms of the sequence, given the choice allowed for functions and absolute values.

Comment: @mattecapu It is circular. Anything concrete is needed.

Comment: Didn't you say, in your question that you wanted a proof that it can't be done? Then why am I, when I ask you to clarify the rules of the game for the sole reason that a _think_ it is broken and needs specification, the one asked for evidence? By the way, take a look at $5|n+1|-4|n|$.

Comment: @Arthur I never did attempt it before, so for me a proof for not attempting was needed. That was my level and based on that, wanted a proof. Now, my horizon has expanded by your answer. So, question also altered. Please tell a suitable source of such questions. It was just a coincidence that this question occurred to me, as have done elementary proofs in number theory and hence felt how better it could be if a proof were there.

Comment: @Arthur Please tell any source that asks finding $n$th term in sequences as this. I have only attempted very simple questions till now in sequences, that are obvious enough.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Please restate your answer, I have not noted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $n$th term in your sequence is
$$
4\frac{|n-1/2|}{n-1/2} + n
$$

So it can be represented by a formula, if the formula is allowed to use absolute values.

Comment: Any good source for such questions. I actually was doing a question from first exercise of  the book by Valentin Goranko, on logic, that this occurred to me.

Comment: Please tell any starting point in this case,  on which such formula can be guessed. I mean how one should approach the issue, in this case, to get the given formula. That will make me self-reliant, and enable me to build answer, rather than just asking.

Comment: I don't know of a specific source. In general you can always find some way to express piecewise linear functions on the real line as a combination of absolute values, except maybe for some difficulties at the endpoints of your pieces. Fundamentally this boils down to linear algebra (i.e., showing that the functions $\{1, x, |x-a|, \frac{|x-a|}{x-a}\}$ span the space of piecewise linear functions), but it feels more like the kind of thing that would be set as an exercise than the kind of thing that you would actually see a proof of somewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such information, not accessible by me till now anywhere. It arose out of curiosity, based on some experience in doing proofs, and it has led to a new way to think. I hope then all sequences must be representable by a formula, just need to be able to formulate.

Comment: I wouldn't say "all sequences", but pretty much any sequence you can actually define. Certainly going from sequences defined by a single formula to sequences defined piecewise doesn't get you any more generality. People usually don't do this just because the single formula you get is usually complicated and unilluminating. (The formula that Christian and I gave you isn't that hard to understand, but this is still a relatively simple case, and something like $\begin{cases}n-4,&n\leq 0\\ n+4,&n>0\end{cases}$ would be even clearer.)

Comment: Yes, this (piece-wise) is the sort of formula I am familiar with. Regarding the possibility of all sequences being definable by a formula - I hope it becomes quite simple if piece-wise approach is taken first, and then transformed to a single one. I hope that the complexity to derive any formula reduces to finding a single formula that states all the piece-wise formulas then.

Comment: Also, the need to find a general formula that combines all the piece-wise formulas is the approach to state the formula. But, then the starting point is to state all the piece-wise formulas then.